# Get size of memory access with non-primitive type

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to get the size of memory access (load) using

```
dyn_cast<LoadInst>(Inst)->getType()->getPrimitiveSizeinBits()
```

which works for most cases.

However, for load instructions like

```
%18 = load i8*, i8** %11, align 8, !tbaa !10
```

where we have double star (**) pointer access, such method would only return a value of 0. I am wondering is there any method that could allow me to get the size of loading in this case?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the type of the primitive regardless of how many indirection levels are there,
you could do something like this:

```
llvm::Type *t = [...]; // getting the type varies on instruction and operand required

while(t && t->isPointerTy()) {
  t = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::PointerType>(t)->getElementType();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointer size is target-dependent, so you need to go through the `Module`'s `DataLayout`. You probably want something like [`M.getDataLayout().getTypeAllocSizeInBits(Ty)`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#a136b0694f04fcaaa2e86b47fe15f3fed).